# I am unable to use geolocation in react-native with redux

Tags: api, react-native, redux, geolocation, maps

I am using geolocation in react-native with redux, but I am getting 2 problems..

1. It's showing wrong latitude and longitude in my android studio emulator, my location is lahore, pakistan but It's showing USA location.
2. When i signed it apk file and installed that apk file in my mobile then It's not showing any location, empty.

Can anyone help me?

Here is my code..!

Reducer.js

```
let initialState = {
    lng: null,
    lat: null,
}

export default function prayerTimes(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {

         case GET_LOCATION:
             return {
                ...state,
                lat: action.lat,
                lng: action.lng
         }

    }
}
```

Action.js

```
export function getLocation() {
    return dispatch => {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_LOCATION,
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            });
        });
    };
}
```

App.js

```
componentDidMount() {
    const { getLocation } = this.props;
    getLocation();
}

render() {
   const { lng, lat } = this.props;
   return (
       <View style={{justifyContent: 'center'}}>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Latitude: {lat}</Text>
            <Text style={{color: 'white'}}>Latitude: {lng}</Text>
       </View>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried enabling high accuracy?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    (position) => {
        dispatch({
            type: GET_LOCATION,
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        });
    },
    (error) => {},
    { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 },
);
```

Comment: The high accuracy option will take a little longer, make sure to add the proper timeout value as well.

Comment: sure, but can i change maximumAge from 1000 to 10,000 ?

Comment: Not recomended. Maximum age is like a cache. If you set it too high, it will never updates.

Comment: when i installed this app in my mobile then it's not showing any location, just like empty world

Answer (score 0):

This below code works for me to get my current country name.

```
constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                lat: null,
                long: null,
            };
          }

          componentDidMount ()  {    
            navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                (position) => {
                   var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
                   var long = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

                   this.setState({ lat: lat, long: long });
                },
                (error) => {  },
            ); 
            }

            componentDidUpdate () {

                var pos = {
                    lat: this.state.lat,
                    lng: this.state.long,
                };

           Geocoder.geocodePosition(pos).then(res => {  // import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoder';
               AsyncStorage.setItem('location',res[0].country); // res[0].country gives you the country name of your location
          })
                .catch(error => alert(error));

            }
```

Comment: It  is in react-native, i don't know how to convert code from react-native to react-native redux..

Comment: I'm sorry. I've never used Redux.